# SQL ambigutiy when trying to display

Tags: mysql, sql, select

Consider the following query i tried, there two tables, Orders and Customers, each have column name CustomerID, when i try to display both CustomerID's only one column is displaying, i can't understand why is it so, or am i understanding the basics wrong.

```
SELECT Customers.CustomerID,Orders.CustomerID
FROM customers
inner JOIN orders
on customers.customerid=orders.customerid;
```

When i try to display only one column it is displaying well and good

```
SELECT Customers.CustomerID
FROM customers
inner JOIN orders
on customers.customerid=orders.customerid;
```

and

```
SELECT Customers.CustomerID
FROM customers
inner JOIN orders
on customers.customerid=orders.customerid;
```

So my problem is why I cant display the both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a peculiarity of some query interfaces.  Your first query (which I would write like this) is:

```
SELECT c.CustomerID, o.CustomerID
FROM customers c INNER JOIN
     orders o
     ON c.customerid = o.customerid;
```

This returns two columns, both named `CustomerId`.  Some query interfaces insist that the resulting columns be unique in the result set.  Hence, the results ignore "subsequent" columns with the same name.

You can get a flavor of this by using the query as a subquery:

```
SELECT x.*
FROM (SELECT c.CustomerID, o.CustomerID
      FROM customers c INNER JOIN
           orders o
           ON c.customerid = o.customerid
     ) x;
```

This should return an error, because `CustomerId` is ill-defined.

Three points to remember:

- Most databases and query interfaces allow result sets with multiple columns with the same name.
- No database allows multiple columns with the same name in a subquery.
- You know how to fix this by assigning a column alias, which is a best-practice anyway.

Answer (score 4):

use alias

```
SELECT Customers.CustomerID as customerid,Orders.CustomerID as ocustomerid
FROM customers
inner JOIN orders
on customers.customerid=orders.customerid;
```

Comment: @aswinmythili Because in your application code, the variable gets over-written.

Comment: Can't understand in detail @yafater

Comment: when you have two columns with same names you can use alias names (by as) to make difference between them.

Answer (score 2):

You need to define an alias for each column:

```
SELECT Customers.CustomerID as customer_id, Orders.CustomerID as order_id
FROM customers
inner JOIN orders
on customers.customerid=orders.customerid;
```